# Replace the start and end of a string ignoring the middle with regex, how?

Tags: c#, regex

I am using c# regex.replace and I want to replace this string:

```
test = "<p align=\"center\"><b><font size=\"4\">RWGRF-W02PS-PU-BU-FLD</font></b></p>";

with: <center><b><font size=\"4\">RWGRF-W02PS-PU-BU-FLD</font></b><center>";
```

Now I could quite easily do this with two calls to replace but the

is used for lots of things, so I need to do it in one go, is there anyway to do this replace all in one call to regex?

Ive tried using .+ to match anything in the middle of the string, but then it obviously replaces the entire middle of the string as well, I want it to ignore that part of the string and not touch it, I know there is a way I just can't figure it out. Also I appreciate answers but if someone can explain how it works that would be even better :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the match with parenthesis, and then replace it.

```
 exp = new Regex(@"YourtagStartRegex(bodyRegex)YourtagClosingRegex");
 str = exp.Replace(str, "<center>$1</center>");
```

Comment: And of course you could just use static strings for the opening and closing tags and (.+) as the matching body.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private static readonly Regex pRegex =
    new Regex("^<p align=\"center\">(.*)</p>$");

public static string ReplaceString(string input)
{
    return pRegex.Replace(input,
        match => "<center>" + match.Groups[1].Value + "</center>");
}
```

Obviously, change the name of the method and Regex variable to whatever names make more sense for your particular application.