# Regular expression replace start and end, ignore middle

Tags: regex, ant

In an Ant build file, is there a way to use a replaceregexp to find and replace two tags, and retain what's in between them? For example, to find all of these:

```
</a>1234abcdefg</P>

</a>123456789. </p>

</a> yop </p> 

</a></p>
```

and replace

```
</a> and </p>
```

with

```
<@> and <@@>
```

so that I have, respectively:

```
<@>1234abcdefg@@

<@>123456789. <@@>

<@> yop <@@>

<@><@@>
```

I can't replace the tags individually since they occur in other places, I just want the instances in which `</a>` is followed by `</p>`, in the same line, with either nothing or something in between them, and I want to keep what's in between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<replaceregexp file="notTested.xml" match="(&lt;)\/a(&gt;.*?&lt;)\/p(&gt;)" replace="\1@\2@@\3" byline="true" flags="g" />
```

as for, `but it replaces what's between the tags with .*` , i haven't seen `.*` in a replacement/substitution expression. probably it takes it as literals `.` and `*`.

as for `&lt;/a&gt;.*&lt;/p&gt;`, the `&gt; .* &lt;` will not work when you have multiple declerations of `</a>` and `</p>` on the same line... such as:

`</a>1234abcdefg</P>abcde</a>123456789. </p>` would be replaced as

`<@>1234abcdefg</P>abcde</a>123456789. <@@>`

you need to use non greedy quantifier `?`. See [**WiKi**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Examples) for the use of `.*?` vs `.*`.

Comment: Your "try this" worked perfectly. Also helped me see why it worked, so now I understand the principle involved. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: You can try this

You store the match with parenthesis, and then replace it.

exp = new Regex(@"YourtagStartRegex(bodyRegex)YourtagClosingRegex");
 str = exp.Replace(str, "$1");

Reference:[Replace the start and end of a string ignoring the middle with regex, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4486451/replace-the-start-and-end-of-a-string-ignoring-the-middle-with-regex-how)

Or

Solution 2:

[Regex ignore middle part of capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768321/regex-ignore-middle-part-of-capture)

Comment: I had seen that first answer but I couldn't get it to work. Could you show how that looks in an Ant task perhaps, and even better, using my examples above? I don't understand where `exp` goes an an Ant target, and what `bodyRegex` contains. Thanks.